# Error in connection with mysql, hibernate and tomcat7

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have developed one web application using Spring, Hibernate and MySQL. Everything runs well on local server but when i made it live and try to login the system, It gives me the following error.

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01

ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communication link failure: java.io.IOException, underlying cause: Unexpected end of input stream


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 


java.io.IOException
MESSAGE: Unexpected end of input stream

STACKTRACE:

java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of input stream
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1455)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1826)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1192)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2051)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1496)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1669)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2145)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2029)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2024)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:111)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1655)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:164)
at com.medical.util.HibernateUtil.getCurrentDate(HibernateUtil.java:34)
at com.medical.util.HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession(HibernateUtil.java:26)
at com.medical.model.LoginModel.checkForAuthentication(LoginModel.java:26)
at com.medical.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: Is the MySQL version the same on local server and on live server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you are using an older MySQL driver with a newer MySQL database. Make sure you are using the latest version of the MySQL Connector/J.

Comment: I have installed mysql  5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu) and the mysql-connector is mysql-connector-java-3.0.10.jar. So may i know what changes do i need to make? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your version of the MySql connector is old. Try using the latest version (5.1.32). You can get it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Hi, Thanks David. Thanks Knowarth. It was really helpful and my problem is resolved.......Thanks again